# BERT error: Cannot squeeze a dimension whose value is not 1

Tags: pytorch, coreml, bert-language-model

I have an mlmodel based on pytorch-pretrained-BERT, exported via ONNX to CoreML. That process was pretty smooth, so now I'm trying to do some (very) basic testing—i.e., just to make some kind of prediction, and get a rough idea of what performance problems we might encounter.

Howver, when I try to run prediction, I get the following error:

```
[espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Espresso exception: "Invalid state": Cannot squeeze a dimension whose  
value is not 1: shape[1]=128 stat2020-02-16   
11:36:05.959261-0800 Xxxxx[6725:2140794] [coreml] Error computing NN outputs -5
```

Is this error indicating a problem with the model itself (i.e., from model conversion), or is there something in Swift/CoreML that I'm doing wrong? My prediction function looks like this:

```
public func prediction(withInput input: String) -> MLMultiArray? {
        var predictions: MLMultiArray? = nil
        if let bert = bertMLModel {
            var ids = tokenizer.tokenizeToIds(text: input, includeWordpiece: true)
            print("ids: \(ids)")
            while ids.count < 256 {
                ids.append(0)
            }
            let inputMLArray = MLMultiArray.from(ids, dims: 2)
            let modelInput = bert_256_FP16Input(input_ids: inputMLArray)
            var modelOutput: bert_256_FP16Output? = nil
            do {
                modelOutput = try bert.prediction(input: modelInput)
            } catch {
                print("Error running prediction: \(error)")
            }
            if let modelOutput = modelOutput {
                predictions = modelOutput.output_weights
            }
        }
        return predictions
    }
```

I'm not trying to do anything meaningful, at this stage, only to get it running.

I used the pytorch-pretrained-BERT repo because I was able to find a ground-up pretraining example for that. I have since noticed that HuggingFace has released a "from scratch" training option, but there are still some issues with the tutorial that are being sorted out. So I would like to at least understand what might be going wrong with my current model/approach. However, if the problem is definitely in the PyTorch->ONNX->CoreML conversion, then I don't really want to fight that fight and will just dig into what HuggingFace is offering.

Any thoughts appreciated.

UPDATE: On Matthijs' advice, I'm trying to predict from the model in python:

```
from coremltools.models import *
import numpy as np

# Just a "dummy" input, but it is a valid series of tokens for my data.
tokens = [3, 68, 45, 68, 45,  5, 45, 68, 45,  4]
tokens_tensor = np.zeros((1, 128))
for i in range(0, 10):
    tokens_tensor[0, i] = tokens[I]
# I'm doing masked token prediction, so one segment.
segments_tensor = np.zeros((1, 128))

mlmodel = 'bert_fp16.mlmodel'

model = MLModel(mlmodel)
spec = model.get_spec()
print("spec: ", spec.description)

predictions = model.predict({'input.1': np.asarray(tokens_tensor, dtype=np.int32), 'input.3': np.asarray(segments_tensor, dtype=np.int32)})
```

I admit I haven't run an mlmodel from python before, but I think the inputs are correct. The spec indicates:

```
input {
  name: "input.1"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      shape: 128
      dataType: INT32
    }
  }
}
input {
  name: "input.3"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      shape: 128
      dataType: INT32
    }
  }
}
...
```

for my inputs.

For this case, I don't get the `cannot squeeze` message, or the error code (-5), but it does fail with `Error computing NN outputs`. So something is definitely wrong. I'm just not at all sure how to go about debugging it.

J.

UPDATE: For comparison I've trained/converted the HuggingFace BERT Model (actually, DistilBert — I've updated the code above accordingly) and have the same error. Looking at the log from onnx, I see that there is one `Squeeze` added (also clear from the onnx-coreml log, of course), but the only `squeeze` in the PyTorch code is in `BertForQuestionAnswering`, not `BertForMaskedLM`. Perhaps onnx is building the question answering model, not the mlm one (or the question answering one is being saved in the checkpoint)?

Looking at the swift-coreml-transformers sample code I can see that distilBert's input is just `let input_ids = MLMultiArray.from(allTokens, dims: 2)`, which is exactly how I've defined it. So I'm at a dead-end, I think. Has anybody managed to run MLM with Bert/DistilBert in CoreML (via onnx)? If so, an example would be super helpful.

I'm training using the latest `run_language_modeling.py` from HuggingFace, btw.

Looking at the mlmodel in Netron, I can see the offending `squeeze`. I confess that I don't know what that branch of the input is for, but I'm guessing it's a mask (and a further guess might be that it has to do with question answering). Could I just remove that somehow?

[image]

Comment: I would try running this model in Python to see if that gives the same error message. It might be something related to how you create the MLMultiArrays, but if Python also gives the same message it's likely something in the mlmodel file itself.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans, you solved this problem over on GitHub: https://github.com/huggingface/swift-coreml-transformers/issues/16#issuecomment-592153661. If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks!